# Python dictionary only stores last values in new dictionary entries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file (`data1`) that contains (latitude, longitude, time) and I want to pull out specific (latitude, longitude) points. To do this, I use a dictionary.

```
lats=[20,40]
lons=[-135,-75]
names=['jib', 'jibb']
d={}
for i in lats:
    for j in lons:
        for k in names:
            d[k]=data1.sel(latitude=i).sel(longitude=j)
```

This is just an example where the data is meaningless. However, when I print out `jib` and `jibb` they have the same exact latitude and longitude. Why is this? What I want is for `jib` to have lat=20 and lon=-135, while `jibb` has lat=40 and lon=-75.

```
d['jib']


time: 44160
Coordinates:
longitude
()
float32
-75.0
latitude
()
float32
40.0

d['jibb']


time: 44160
Coordinates:
longitude
()
float32
-75.0
latitude
()
float32
40.0
```

Comment: use `zip()` it can be helpful and nested loops is not needed

Comment: You are iterating over all eight permutations of your two lats, two lons, and two names.  Only the last values stored with each name were kept in the dictionary, because they overwrote the three previous permutations stored with the same name.

Comment: How do I prevent that?

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with zip(). Feel free to suggest a solution that incorporates it.

Comment: Nice, this works as desired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip()` you can create a generator that loops over all of your iterables simultaneously. When iterables are zipped a new `iterable` is returned containing tuples of *same-index* values from each `iterable` that was provided.

```
#Example Zip Return ~ based on your data

names = ['jib', 'jibb']
lats  = [20,40]
lons  = [-135,-75]

print(list(zip(names, lats lons)))  #[('jib', 20, -135), ('jibb', 40, -75)]
```

When you use `zip()` in a generator you are simply unpacking those tuples at each iteration.

```
#Solution: 

d = {k:data1.sel(latitude=lt).sel(longitude=ln) for k, lt, ln in zip(names, lats, lons)}
```

**notes:**

- If the iterables provided to `zip()` have different lengths, the length of the `iterable` returned from `zip()` will be the same as the shortest iterable provided.

  ```
  a = [1, 2, 3]
  b = ['a', 'b']

  print(list(zip(a, b)))  #[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
  ```
- The provided iterables do not have to match in type, they just have to qualify as an `iterable` type.

  ```
  a = (1, 2, 3)
  b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  c = range(3)

  print(list(zip(a, b, c)))  #[(1, 'a', 0), (2, 'b', 1), (3, 'c', 2)]
  ```